# jquery slider accepts droppable image

Tags: jquery

I am facing problem in drag and drop.When i drop my  first image in slider the images dropped in slider and starts sliding.when i drop my second image in same slider the image comes but below the first one and continues sliding.Actually i want my images to be dropped in a horizontal manner.But my images are comes in a vertical manner .Please help me out.. Here is my code:

```
<div class="slider5">



<div class="slide">



<div class="demo" id="demo">



</div>



 </div>



</div>
```

css part begins...

```
.demo{
    max-width:800px;
    width: 55px;
    min-height:60px;
    max-height: 70px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none; 
    position: relative; 
    margin-right: 2px;
    }
.demo div 
 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

and js parts begins here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                    $('.slider5').bxSlider({
                           slideWidth:700,
                           minSlides: 1,
                           maxSlides: 10,
                           moveSlides: 1,
                           slideMargin: 2,
                           auto: true,
                        slideDirection: "horizontal", 
                        autoControls: true
                         });

                         });
```

demo is a id through which i makes droppable..

Comment: hello where is your code ???????????????

Comment: I have written some part of my code .where  i am facing problem.

Comment: can you add some code hear http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: we have no idea what your drop code or css looks like. How can anyone help without those?

Comment: the droppable area works perfectly.And i have given the code where i have found an error...

Comment: WOW, i just answered 3 other questions with the data you have provided. cmon, just 6 lines of markup wont give any idea to anyone.

Comment: sorry i forgot to use css..thanks..

Comment: we'd need a link, but if you are saying it doesnt look right, then the css could be wrong

Comment: @atmd: I have used that much css..to make slider to accepts droppable image and for that i also used this links..<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>                                                                     <script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />